# download multiple pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download multiple pdf's as attachments in my asp.net application.I have created some templates and filling values using pdfstamper(itextsharp). I am able to fill the values but not able to download.

```
private void FillForm(string path, DataTable BridgeValues, DataTable Comments, DataTable Maintenance,string Newfilename)
    {
        try
        {
            string pdfTemplate = path;
            string newFile = Newfilename;
            string Pathser = "";
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/")))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/"));
            }

            if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/")))
            {
               Pathser = Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/" + Newfilename);
            }
            System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(Pathser, FileMode.Create));
            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            DataColumn dc = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < BridgeValues.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dc = BridgeValues.Columns[i];
                pdfFormFields.SetField(dc.ColumnName.ToString(),  BridgeValues.Rows[0][dc].ToString());
            }
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

            // close the pdf
            pdfStamper.Close();
            ////Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            ////Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.pdf");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Newfilename + "");
            ////Response.BinaryWrite(mStream.ToArray());
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(("~/PDF/"+ Newfilename)));
            Response.Clear();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException lException)
        {

            // do nothing

        }
    }
```

First time I tried to create one pdf ,it worked but later when I tried to download multiple files it gave an execption.
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: Why are you catching ThreadAbortException? It'll be rethrown automatically, but you shouldn't be catching it... As for the exception - that *wouldn't* have included the "Unable to evaluate expression..." part - that's just what the debugger shows, it's not part of the exception.

Comment: that was the final try i did,there was some execption "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack." so i tried the catch part.

Comment: No, that's *not* the exception. It really, really isn't. It's just what's showing in the debugger. If you look in the exception for the message, it won't be that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can download multiple files by making one request and returning a collection from the action. I would suggest that it you need to allow user to download multiple files you ZIP them and stream the archive down to the browser.

Here is an example of zipping multiple files: http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2008/01/25/how-to-create-zip-files-in-c-with-sharpziplib-ziplib.aspx

Comment: i was looping through the number of files and downloading them,but it is bad idea.as you said i would download them as a zip.can i save many files on server and download them as a zip??any examples?